# How do I change the height of a button in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I was trying to create a flashing "Contact Us" button on the menu bar of my website so it would immediately catch people's attention as soon as they enter the site. This is the javascript I used:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function blinker()
{
    document.getElementById("btnBlink").style.backgroundColor="red";
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('btnBlink').style.backgroundColor=''", 500);
    setTimeout("blinker()",1500);
}

window.onload=blinker;
</script>
```

And this what I used in for HTML

```
<li id="menu-item-1639" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1639"><a href="http://WebsiteNameGoesHere.com/contact-us/"><input type="button" value="Contact Us" id="btnBlink" /></a></li>
```

So I managed to make it blink red but the button isn't aligned with the other links in the menu bar. It's located a bit higher than it's supposed to be. I want to bring the "Contact Us" button lower.

Comment: Don't use `setTimeout` nor `setInterval` with strings, because it's like evil `eval`! Use functions instead: `setTimeout(blinker,1500)`

Comment: Please show your CSS and the rest of your HTML; it's impossible to tell what's wrong otherwise. (also, @Oriol's advice is very pertinent)

Comment: Why don't you create a flashing button with css?

Answer (score 0):

use css3 animation, or simply setInterval from Javascript:
    
    `var isVisible = true;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
    var elem = document.querySelector(".your-selector");
    if(isVisible) {
    elem.style.opacity = 1;
    } else elem.style.opacity = 0;
    isVisible = !isVisible;
    }, 1000);`

Comment: But how do I change the height?